# Hide tab for current view controller in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I was just wondering how I can hide the tab item in the `Tab Bar Controller` for the current view controller which is selected

Comment: How can you select other tabs when its hidden in current view???

Comment: Are you working in Swift or ObjC?

Comment: @Wezly Working in ObjC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think it's possible to hide a `UITabBarItem` - It inherits from `UIBarItem` but there is no `hidden` property - [UIBarItem Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem)

You could try comparing the tab bars `selectedViewController` property against your current view controller? - Something like below might work..

```
if (self.tabBarController.selectedViewController == self) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

But even then I think you are going to find it hard to hide the tab bar item itself.

Comment: Yeah, after reading some more. I figured the best solution for my situation, is to remove it completely, once done with that view controller. i.e. the login screen.

Answer (score 3):

Remove intended index from controllersArray ex. (1)

```
NSMutableArray *controllersArray = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithArray:self.tabBar.viewControllers];
[controllersArray removeObjectAtIndex: 1];
[self.tabBar setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```

Check for this answer also I found this similar from your question [Hide tab bar item and aligning other tab items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985869/hide-tab-bar-item-and-aligning-other-tab-items)
Hope this helps you.!!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *parent = self.tabBarController.tabBar.superview; // UILayoutContainerView
    UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0];  // UITransitionView
    UIView *window = parent.superview;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect tabFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
                         tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds);
                         self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
                         content.frame = window.bounds;
                     }];
```